# iOS - Push Notification not working in TestFlight with Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile

Tags: php, ios, iphone, notifications

I am just trying my app before the actually release using "TestFlight".

To setup the Push Notification I have used this [tutorial and script](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1). In development I can receive the notification to all the devices installed however, when I try to send notification to Ad Hoc Build the notification are not receiving. I know that the tokes are different and I think I use the correct ones.

I have created the certificate for Production and the App ID has Push Notification Enabled for distribution.

I have created the Provisioning Profile adding all the devices that will test the app.

After all this when I try to send a Push Notification using this [php script](http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/SimplePush.zip)
the script shows that the message has been sent ok but I don't receive any notification.

What am I doing wrong?
Is Ad Hoc build supports Push Notifications?

could be that I am using `ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195` asa socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be the url.  'sandbox' is a development APNS type.  You could try ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195
The Apple doc is good for debugging:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html